# How to append header to the remaining lines in a multi header csv file using UNIX

Tags: linux, unix

I have a csv file with the data like below:

```
header1
abc
def
header2
ghi
jkl
header3
mno
pqr
```

I need the output as below:

```
header1 header1
header1 abc
header1 def
header2 header2
header2 ghi
header2 jkl
header3 header3
header3 mno
header3 pqr
```

can anyone let me know how to achieve this in UNIX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR%3==1{ hdr=$1 }{ print hdr,$1 }' file
header1 header1
header1 abc
header1 def
header2 header2
header2 ghi
header2 jkl
header3 header3
header3 mno
header3 pqr
```

Comment: Thanks Freddy, how to achieve this If the lines are varying under each header

Comment: Does the header always begin with a common prefix like `header`? Or how do you identify the header? Number of characters in line > 3?

Comment: yes header begins with common prefix something like dn:

Comment: Change it to `awk '/^dn:/{ hdr=$1 }{ print hdr,$1 }' file`.